# Gatling test fails when digest authentication on

Tags: web-services, digest-authentication, gatling

I recently developped a SOAP web service.
I started to implement it without authentication. It works fine : the service, the call with SOAP UI and the gatling tests.

I added a digest authentication and now I cannot make my gatling test work (the test with SOAP UI is still successful).
According to the gatling documentation ([here](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/http/http_request.html#authentication)), I am supposed to call `.digestAuth(login, pass)` on my http request:

```
val scn = scenario("scenario")
.feed(feeder)
.feed(feeder2)
.forever{
  exec(
     http("myRequest")
     .post(target)
      .digestAuth("login","pass")
     .body(ELFileBody("Request.wsdl"))
     .headers(headers_2)
      )
 }
```

The answer from the server is always a 500 error with the message :

> Jul 07, 2015 4:27:31 PM com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityRecipient processMessagePolicy
>   SCHWERWIEGEND: WSS0253: Message does not conform to configured policy: No Security Header found in message

UPDATE :

I'm using the latest version of gatling 2.1.6

I cannot share my webservice but here is how it is configured.

spring-servlet.xml

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="policyConfiguration" value="classpath:securityPolicy.xml" />
        <property name="callbackHandlers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="passwordValidationHandler" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</sws:interceptors>

<bean id="passwordValidationHandler"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
    <property name="users">
        <props>
            <prop key="user">password</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And the securityPolicy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config">
  <xwss:RequireUsernameToken passwordDigestRequired="true" nonceRequired="true" />
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

UPDATE 2:
Here is the full request and response from gatling logs:

```
10:06:57.243 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.AsyncHandlerActor - Request 'post_Addresscheck' failed:
status.find.in(200,304,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209), but
actually found 500
10:06:57.244 [TRACE] i.g.h.a.AsyncHandlerActor - http://localhost:8000/ROOT/checkAddresshttp://localhost:8000/ROOT/checkAddress
headers=
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1830
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8000
Accept: */*
realm=Realm{principal='user', password='password', scheme=DIGEST, realmName='', nonce='', algorithm='MD5', response='', qop='auth', nc='00000001', cno
nce='', uri='null', methodName='GET', useAbsoluteURI='true', omitQuery='false'}
=========================
HTTP response:
status=
500 Internal Server Error
headers=
Server: [Apache-Coyote/1.1]
Accept: [text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2]
SOAPAction: [""]
Content-Type: [text/xml;charset=utf-8]
Content-Length: [605]
Date: [Thu, 09 Jul 2015 08:06:57 GMT]
Connection: [close]
```

Did I miss something in my test definition?

Comment: Which version of Gatling do you use? Can you share a reproducer application (your webservice with digest auth).

Comment: My answers in the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Digest auth can't be preemptive, on contrary to basic. The client has to first send a plain request, so the server can reply with 401 and the nonce. Only then can the client send the authenticated request. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication. So a first plain request is expected. What's the full requests and responses? Are you sure you can't provide a simple sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be a confusion here: Gatling supports HTTP digest auth, not WSS digest auth (where creds are passed as a SOAP header, inside the body, instead of a HTTP header).